# Getting HTML value to correlate to JavaScript Value

Tags: javascript, html, select

I'm trying to build 5 select boxes. The value on each box would change the JavaScript "card value" at the very bottom. This would all update the "count" and should I bet expression.

https://jsbin.com/vasaqej/edit?html,js,output

```js
var count = 0;
var shouldIBet = "";


function cc(card) {
  switch(card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
      count++
      break;
    case 10:
    case "J":
    case "Q":
    case "K":
    case "A":
      count--
      break;
  }
  if (count >0) {
    return shouldIBet = " Bet!";
  } else {
    return shouldIBet =  " Hold!";
  }

  return "enter something else"
}
cc(2); cc(3); cc(4); cc(5); cc(5);

document.write(count + shouldIBet)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
  <option value = 2>2</option>
  <option value = 3>3</option>
  <option value = 4>4</option>
  <option value = 5>5</option>
  <option value = 6>6</option>
  <option value = 7>7</option>
  <option value = 8>8</option>
  <option value = 9>9</option>
  <option value = 10>10</option>
  <option value = "J">J</option>
  <option value = "Q">Q</option>
  <option value = "K">K</option>
  <option value = "A">A</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the HTML select values to transfer to the JavaScript values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` Event in your select. Just change `<select>` to `<select onchange="cc(value)">` and everytime you select a new value, the function `cc` will be called with the current value.

You can take a look at this [here](https://jsbin.com/vasaqej/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: hmm... Maybe i wasnt too clear... Currently I have one selection list. There should be five but i'd rather just get one working... at the bottom of the javascript there are five values of "cc" I'm trying to link the value of each select tag to update one of the "cc" values

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
var e = document.getElementById("btnselect");
var boxvalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(boxvalue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="btnselect"  onchange="myFunction();">
  <option value = 2>2</option>
  <option value = 3>3</option>
  <option value = 4>4</option>
  <option value = 5>5</option>
  <option value = 6>6</option>
  <option value = 7>7</option>
  <option value = 8>8</option>
  <option value = 9>9</option>
  <option value = 10>10</option>
  <option value = "J">J</option>
  <option value = "Q">Q</option>
  <option value = "K">K</option>
  <option value = "A">A</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```